# In a double gang box 3 wires and a ground, part 2

Tags: electrical

New information: red, black hot, white and ground.  Pulled panel cover and found red wire DOES go to separate, non-adjacent breaker, but black wire breaker turns them both off.??  Ostensibly on the black wire circuit are closet switch, master bath room vanity switch/outlet and GFCI, shower room light switch and exhaust fan, one wall outlet, and subject Main bathroom switch and GFCI.  I was trying to change switch to switch outlet combo and cannot rewire effectively.  Red wire breaker is mapped to garage at other end of house, but I didn’t do the mapping.  So could this be the same red wire; the lights in the garage are still working but I haven’t checked all outlets.

Comment: This is very alarming.  For two wires in the same /3 cable to land on *non-adjacent* breakers is alarming.   They need to be either a 2-pole breaker or two breakers that occupy the same space as a 2-pole breaker would.  Failing to do this was alwys illegal even before the days of handle ties.

Comment: Yes, on a previous occasion a month or so ago we had a Hall light not working and called an electrician who subsequently reported that the wiring was screwy.  I’ll just go ahead and call him again.  Time to give up.  I’ll write back what happens

Comment: Here’s a wierd one.  Tried the ceiling fan and light in the Master bedroom.  Neither works.  Now, recall that I rewired the outlet switch in the master bathroom which had two cables coming in with black and white each and installed a switch outlet in place of the switch which had broken and the gfci all of which work and check out with the”8” ball tester.  But since trying to turn on the ceiling fan now the former red wire in the mwbc is cold. The breaker with the red wire is not tripped. Electrician comes out tomorrow